# Does Jack from Jack and the Beanstalk ever appear in OuaT?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

The television series Once upon a Time has incorporated fairy tale characters including Snow White, Red Riding Hood and Rumpelstiltskin- has the title character of Jack and the Beanstalk ever made an appearance on the show?

Comment: [spoilers]In the final season "Hansel" poses as "Jack" for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, but with the inevitable Once Upon a Time twist**

In the Once Upon A Time version of the story, the character of Jack is switched for a woman named Jacqueline who calls herself Jack for short. She is portrayed by Cassidy Freeman.

[image: Cassidy Freeman as Jacqueuline]

Her story is told in the episode "Tiny" (season 2, episode 13). Spoilers for her story below.

> She and Prince James befriend Anton the giant, but betray him by trying to steal all of the magic beans. However, she is stabbed by Arlo the giant and James leaves her to die. Emma finds her remains in an earlier season 2 episode "Tallahassee."